# Breeze unable to locate foreign key property

Tags: sql, angularjs

I've updated all my HotTowel angular packages to the latest breeze EF6 and using the the new angular service. I'm getting this error: unable to locate property: rackId on entityType: FarmObject. 
rackId is a foreign key to a table named Racks. (one to many relationship) I'm using the EF6 code first fluent api. The db is seeded correctly I have other tables with the exact same configuration and the foreign keys are correctly identified. My metadata looks ok, I am using the default camelCasing.. I'm hoping someone has come across something similar. Is there anything specific which may cause this? I have the same issue in one other foreign key.
I am using the following packages:

```
         <package id="Breeze.Client" version="1.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
         <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
         <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
         <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this weird behavior. The problem was actually in my seeded test data. After clearing that out and clearing the browser cache it is now working as expected.